# How do I Search a BindingList and return an Object?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project for school that has to follow a certain UML diagram. They're wanting the code to return an object(Part) given an Int(associatedPartID).

I've tried using a foreach loop, and I keep encountering the problem of not all code paths returning a value. Is there a way I could modify it to make it work?

```
    private BindingList<Part> associatedPart;
    private int ProductID;
    private string Name;
    private decimal Price;
    private int InStock;
    private int Min;
    private int Max;

    //getters

    public int getProductID()
    {
        return this.ProductID;
    }

    public string getName()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public decimal getPrice()
    {
        return this.Price;
    }

    public int getInStock()
    {
        return this.InStock;
    }

    public int getMin()
    {
        return this.Min;
    }

    public int getMax()
    {
        return this.Max;
    }

    //setters
    public void setProductID(int productID)
    {
        this.ProductID = productID;
    }

    public void setName(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public void setPrice(decimal price)
    {
        this.Price = price;
    }

    public void setInStock(int instock)
    {
        this.InStock = instock;
    }

    public void setMin(int min)
    {
        this.Min = min;
    }

    public void setMax(int max)
    {
        this.Max = max;
    }

    //methods

    public void addAssociatedPart(Part newAssociatedPart)
    {
        associatedPart.Add(newAssociatedPart);
    }

    public bool removeAssociatedPart(int associatedPartID)
    {

        foreach(Part part in associatedPart)
        {
            if (associatedPartID == part.getPartId())
            {
                associatedPart.Remove(part);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Part lookupAssociatedPart(int associatedPartID)
    {
        foreach(Part part in associatedPart)
        {
            if (associatedPartID == part.getPartId())
            {
                return part;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

So in short, the program would take an associatedPartId and Return the entire Part for that id, which is in a BindingList<>. The method is lookupAssociatedPart(int associatedPartID)

Comment: C# is not Java. Don't write getters and setters. Write properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message describes pretty much your problem, you're missing a return out there. The concrete problem here is that, outside the `foreach` loop, there is no `return` at all. So, what would happen if you ask for an ID that *doesn't exists*? What would it return? That's what the compiler is complaining about.

My guess is that returning `null` would be adequate here (representing no part found), so I'll modify the method in this way:

```
public Part lookupAssociatedPart(int associatedPartID)
{
    foreach(Part part in associatedPart)
    {
        if (associatedPartID == part.getPartId())
        {
            return part;
        }
        //else block omited since it doesn't do anything. continue is implicit at the end of a loop
    }

    //Here we return the value if no part is found
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all section of lookupAssociatedPart function is returning values. The Simple versin of code would be

```
 public Part lookupAssociatedPart(int associatedPartID)
    {
        return associatedPart.Where( a => a.getPartId() == associatedPartID).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```